# How to remove item from ListView and sharedpreferences android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

i want to be able to do this to the code i have already I am new to programing please help.
 - Add an icon the user can click (per item) to remove it
 - When clicked that item on the list should be removed
 -The item should be removed from storage as well (so it doesn't appear next time    they load up the app)
here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
private static final String Log_TAG = "ToDoApp";
private ToDoListManager listManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView todoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todo_list);

    listManager = new ToDoListManager(getApplicationContext());


    ToDoItemAdapter adapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(
            this,
            listManager.getList()
    );




ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAddButtonClick();
        }
    });




}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    listManager.saveList();
}

private void onAddButtonClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_item);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                            input.getText().toString(),
                            false
                    );
                    listManager.addItem(item);


                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}



private class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ToDoItem> items;


    public ToDoItemAdapter(
            Context context,
            List<ToDoItem> items

    ) {
        super(context, -1, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_layout, parent, false);
        }


            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            CheckBox CheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);



            textView.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
            CheckBox.setChecked(items.get(position).isComplete());

            convertView.setTag(items.get(position));


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) v.getTag();
                    item.toggleComplete();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });



            return convertView;





    }




}
    }
```

**todolistmanager.java**

```
public class ToDoListManager  {
private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "todoapp";
private static final String TODO_ITEMS = "itemslist";

private List<ToDoItem> items;
private SharedPreferences savedData;

public ToDoListManager(Context context) {

     savedData = context.getSharedPreferences (
            APP_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    );

    String json = savedData.getString(TODO_ITEMS, null);

    if(json == null) {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<ToDoItem>>() {}.getType();
        items = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    }


}
public  List<ToDoItem> getList() {
    return items;
}

public  void  addItem(ToDoItem item) {
    items.add(item);

    saveList();

}


public  void saveList() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = savedData.edit();
    edit.clear();

    String json = new Gson().toJson(items);
    edit.putString(TODO_ITEMS, json);
    edit.apply();
}
}
```

**todoItem.java**

```
public class ToDoItem {

private String description;
private boolean isComplete;


public  ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete) {
    this.description = description;
    this.isComplete = isComplete;

}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;
}

public boolean isComplete() {

    return isComplete;
}

public void  toggleComplete() {
    isComplete = !isComplete;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getDescription();
}
}
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/hintTxtItem"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lblBtnAdd"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItem"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
    android:text="@string/txtEmpty"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/lblBtnDel" />
```

**to_do_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/lblBtnDel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtItem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItem"
            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvTodo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="No data"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Step2: Create to todo_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Learn Android"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbChooseTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Step3: Define Object Todo

```
public class ToDoItem {

    private String description;
    private boolean isComplete;

    public ToDoItem(String description, boolean isComplete) {
        this.description = description;
        this.isComplete = isComplete;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return isComplete;
    }

    public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
        isComplete = complete;
    }
}
```

Step4: Create TodoItemAdapter class

```
public class TodoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {
    private ArrayList<ToDoItem> arrayListTodo;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public TodoItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ToDoItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.arrayListTodo = objects;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent,false);

            holder.tvTodoName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoName);
            holder.cbTodoChoose = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbChooseTodo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ToDoItem toDoItem = arrayListTodo.get(position);
        holder.tvTodoName.setText(toDoItem.getDescription());
        holder.cbTodoChoose.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                toDoItem.setComplete(isChecked);
            }
        });

        holder.cbTodoChoose.setChecked(toDoItem.isComplete());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView tvTodoName;
        public CheckBox cbTodoChoose;
    }
}
```

Step5: Process on the MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ListView lvTodoItem;
    private ArrayList<ToDoItem> toDoItems;
    private TodoItemAdapter todoItemAdapter;
    private Button btnDel;
    private Button btnAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initData();
    }

    private void initData(){
        toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
        todoItemAdapter = new TodoItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.todo_item, toDoItems);

        lvTodoItem = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTodo);
        lvTodoItem.setAdapter(todoItemAdapter);

        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnDel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                addTodoItem();
                break;
            case R.id.btnDel:
                deleteTodoItem();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void addTodoItem() {

    }

    private void deleteTodoItem() {
        for (int i= toDoItems.size()-1; i>=0 ; i--){
            ToDoItem toDoItem = toDoItems.get(i);
            if (toDoItem.isComplete()){
                toDoItems.remove(i);
            }
        }
        todoItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much but i was hoping you could show me without changing most of my original coding i am new to this so it would easier for me to understand if  you would use my code. Can you please tell me how to make the delete button work? (buy using my code ) thank you so much:)

Comment: Two issues you can focus: 1. Remove item on list. 2. Update adapter by the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: Could you tell me where to implament in my code for the delete button?

Comment: Looking for my code, it has the deleteTodoItem() method. that is method to delete.

Comment: i tried to implement your code but does not work my code always braceks can you show me example please